# Python string formatting for encryption

Tags: python-3.x

I need help figuring out how to do these following thigns for a string
If the character is an uppercase: change it to lowercase with '!' sign on its both sides (e.g. 'M' --> '!m!');
If the character is a lowercase: change it to uppercase with '!' sign on its both sides (e.g. 'm' --> '!M!');
If the character is a digit: cube the digit, i.e. raise to the power of 3 (e.g. '5' --> '125');
If the character is a blank space: replace it with '$' symbol;
Otherwise: keep it as it is.

I don't know where to start, besides a possible loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string = "Mm5 @"
new_string = ""
for char in string:
    if char.isupper():
        new_string += "!" + char.lower() + "!"
    elif char.islower():
        new_string += "!" + char.upper() + "!"
    elif char.isdigit():
        new_string += str(int(char) ** 3)
    elif char == " ":
        new_string += "$"
    else:
        new_string += char
print(new_string)
>> !m!!M!125$@
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the string.
2. According to the transformation rules, transforms each character in the string.
3. Returns the new string.

```
def convertString(input):
    output = ''
    for char in input:
        if char.isupper():
            char = '!' + char.lower() + '!'
            output += char
        elif char.islower():
            char = '!' + char.upper() + '!'
            output += char
        elif char.isdigit():
            char = int(char) * int(char) * int(char)
            char = str(char)
            output += char
        elif char.isspace():
            char = '$'
            output += char
        else:
            char = char
            output += char
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    input = 'Mm 5:)'

    output = convertString(input)

    print(output)
```

**Output**

```
!m!!M!$125:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's answer for your question. It is in Kotlin but you can get the logic and convert it in Python.

```
fun main(){
    println("Enter String: ")
    val str = readln()

    var newString = ""
    for (s in str){
        when{
            s.isDigit() -> newString += (s.digitToInt() * s.digitToInt() * s.digitToInt())

            s.isLowerCase() -> newString += "!" + s.uppercase() + "!"

            s.isUpperCase() -> newString += "!" + s.lowercase() + "!"

            s == ' ' -> newString += "$"
        }
    }
    println("String formatted as: $newString")
}
```